# Strange dist-upgrade, 0xamarin1?

Tags: apt, 16.04, updates, mono, certificates

Can someone explain what "0xamarin1" is and all this "libmono-*" stuff? Are other people also seeing a similar CA update?

```
$ apt-get update && apt-get dist-upgrade -V

Reading package lists... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
   mono-reference-assemblies-2.0 (3.12.1+dfsg-1)
The following NEW packages will be installed:
   gamin (0.1.10-5)
   libbonobo2-0 (2.32.1-3)
   libbonobo2-common (2.32.1-3)
   libbonoboui2-0 (2.24.5-3ubuntu1)
   libbonoboui2-common (2.24.5-3ubuntu1)
   libgail18 (2.24.30-1ubuntu1)
   libgamin0 (0.1.10-5)
   libglade2-0 (1:2.6.4-2)
   libgnome-2-0 (2.32.1-5ubuntu1)
   libgnome2-0 (2.32.1-5ubuntu1)
   libgnome2-bin (2.32.1-5ubuntu1)
   libgnome2-common (2.32.1-5ubuntu1)
   libgnomecanvas2-0 (2.30.3-2)
   libgnomecanvas2-common (2.30.3-2)
   libgnomeui-0 (2.24.5-3.1)
   libgnomeui-common (2.24.5-3.1)
   libgnomevfs2-0 (1:2.24.4-6.1ubuntu1)
   libgnomevfs2-common (1:2.24.4-6.1ubuntu1)
   libmono-system-numerics-vectors4.0-cil (4.4.2.11-0xamarin1)
   libmono-system-reflection-context4.0-cil (4.4.2.11-0xamarin1)
   libmono-system-runtime-interopservices-runtimeinformation4.0-cil (4.4.2.11-0xamarin1)
   libmonosgen-2.0-1 (4.4.2.11-0xamarin1)
   libmonosgen-2.0-dev (4.4.2.11-0xamarin1)
   liborbit-2-0 (1:2.14.19-1build1)
The following packages will be upgraded:
   ca-certificates-mono (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 => 4.4.2.11-0xamarin1)
   clamav (0.99+dfsg-1ubuntu1.1 => 0.99+dfsg-1ubuntu1.2)
   clamav-base (0.99+dfsg-1ubuntu1.1 => 0.99+dfsg-1ubuntu1.2)
   clamav-freshclam (0.99+dfsg-1ubuntu1.1 => 0.99+dfsg-1ubuntu1.2)
   libclamav7 (0.99+dfsg-1ubuntu1.1 => 0.99+dfsg-1ubuntu1.2)
   libcupsfilters1 (1.8.3-2ubuntu3 => 1.8.3-2ubuntu3.1)
   libfontembed1 (1.8.3-2ubuntu3 => 1.8.3-2ubuntu3.1)
   libmono-2.0-dev (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 => 4.4.2.11-0xamarin1)
   libmono-accessibility4.0-cil (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 => 4.4.2.11-0xamarin1)
   libmono-cairo4.0-cil (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 => 4.4.2.11-0xamarin1)
   libmono-cecil-private-cil (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 => 4.4.2.11-0xamarin1)
   libmono-cil-dev (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 => 4.4.2.11-0xamarin1)
   libmono-codecontracts4.0-cil (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 => 4.4.2.11-0xamarin1)
   libmono-compilerservices-symbolwriter4.0-cil (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 => 4.4.2.11-0xamarin1)
   libmono-corlib4.5-cil (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 => 4.4.2.11-0xamarin1)
   libmono-cscompmgd0.0-cil (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 => 4.4.2.11-0xamarin1)
   libmono-csharp4.0c-cil (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 => 4.4.2.11-0xamarin1)
   libmono-custommarshalers4.0-cil (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 => 4.4.2.11-0xamarin1)
   libmono-data-tds4.0-cil (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 => 4.4.2.11-0xamarin1)
   libmono-db2-1.0-cil (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 => 4.4.2.11-0xamarin1)
   libmono-debugger-soft4.0a-cil (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 => 4.4.2.11-0xamarin1)
   libmono-http4.0-cil (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 => 4.4.2.11-0xamarin1)
   libmono-i18n-cjk4.0-cil (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 => 4.4.2.11-0xamarin1)
   libmono-i18n-mideast4.0-cil (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 => 4.4.2.11-0xamarin1)
   libmono-i18n-other4.0-cil (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 => 4.4.2.11-0xamarin1)
   libmono-i18n-rare4.0-cil (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 => 4.4.2.11-0xamarin1)
   libmono-i18n-west4.0-cil (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 => 4.4.2.11-0xamarin1)
   libmono-i18n4.0-all (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 => 4.4.2.11-0xamarin1)
   libmono-i18n4.0-cil (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 => 4.4.2.11-0xamarin1)
   libmono-ldap4.0-cil (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 => 4.4.2.11-0xamarin1)
   libmono-management4.0-cil (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 => 4.4.2.11-0xamarin1)
   libmono-messaging-rabbitmq4.0-cil (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 => 4.4.2.11-0xamarin1)
   libmono-messaging4.0-cil (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 => 4.4.2.11-0xamarin1)
   libmono-microsoft-build-engine4.0-cil (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 => 4.4.2.11-0xamarin1)
   libmono-microsoft-build-framework4.0-cil (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 => 4.4.2.11-0xamarin1)
   libmono-microsoft-build-tasks-v4.0-4.0-cil (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 => 4.4.2.11-0xamarin1)
   libmono-microsoft-build-utilities-v4.0-4.0-cil (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 => 4.4.2.11-0xamarin1)
   libmono-microsoft-build4.0-cil (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 => 4.4.2.11-0xamarin1)
   libmono-microsoft-csharp4.0-cil (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 => 4.4.2.11-0xamarin1)
   libmono-microsoft-visualc10.0-cil (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 => 4.4.2.11-0xamarin1)
   libmono-microsoft-web-infrastructure1.0-cil (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 => 4.4.2.11-0xamarin1)
   libmono-oracle4.0-cil (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 => 4.4.2.11-0xamarin1)
   libmono-parallel4.0-cil (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 => 4.4.2.11-0xamarin1)
   libmono-peapi4.0a-cil (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 => 4.4.2.11-0xamarin1)
   libmono-posix4.0-cil (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 => 4.4.2.11-0xamarin1)
   libmono-rabbitmq4.0-cil (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 => 4.4.2.11-0xamarin1)
   libmono-relaxng4.0-cil (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 => 4.4.2.11-0xamarin1)
   libmono-security4.0-cil (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 => 4.4.2.11-0xamarin1)
   libmono-sharpzip4.84-cil (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 => 4.4.2.11-0xamarin1)
   libmono-simd4.0-cil (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 => 4.4.2.11-0xamarin1)
   libmono-smdiagnostics0.0-cil (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 => 4.4.2.11-0xamarin1)
   libmono-sqlite4.0-cil (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 => 4.4.2.11-0xamarin1)
   libmono-system-componentmodel-composition4.0-cil (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 => 4.4.2.11-0xamarin1)
   libmono-system-componentmodel-dataannotations4.0-cil (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 => 4.4.2.11-0xamarin1)
   libmono-system-configuration-install4.0-cil (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 => 4.4.2.11-0xamarin1)
   libmono-system-configuration4.0-cil (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 => 4.4.2.11-0xamarin1)
   libmono-system-core4.0-cil (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 => 4.4.2.11-0xamarin1)
   libmono-system-data-datasetextensions4.0-cil (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 => 4.4.2.11-0xamarin1)
   libmono-system-data-entity4.0-cil (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 => 4.4.2.11-0xamarin1)
   libmono-system-data-linq4.0-cil (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 => 4.4.2.11-0xamarin1)
   libmono-system-data-services-client4.0-cil (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 => 4.4.2.11-0xamarin1)
   libmono-system-data-services4.0-cil (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 => 4.4.2.11-0xamarin1)
   libmono-system-data4.0-cil (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 => 4.4.2.11-0xamarin1)
   libmono-system-design4.0-cil (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 => 4.4.2.11-0xamarin1)
   libmono-system-drawing-design4.0-cil (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 => 4.4.2.11-0xamarin1)
   libmono-system-drawing4.0-cil (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 => 4.4.2.11-0xamarin1)
   libmono-system-dynamic4.0-cil (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 => 4.4.2.11-0xamarin1)
   libmono-system-enterpriseservices4.0-cil (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 => 4.4.2.11-0xamarin1)
   libmono-system-identitymodel-selectors4.0-cil (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 => 4.4.2.11-0xamarin1)
   libmono-system-identitymodel4.0-cil (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 => 4.4.2.11-0xamarin1)
   libmono-system-io-compression-filesystem4.0-cil (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 => 4.4.2.11-0xamarin1)
   libmono-system-io-compression4.0-cil (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 => 4.4.2.11-0xamarin1)
   libmono-system-json-microsoft4.0-cil (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 => 4.4.2.11-0xamarin1)
   libmono-system-json4.0-cil (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 => 4.4.2.11-0xamarin1)
   libmono-system-ldap-protocols4.0-cil (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 => 4.4.2.11-0xamarin1)
   libmono-system-ldap4.0-cil (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 => 4.4.2.11-0xamarin1)
   libmono-system-management4.0-cil (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 => 4.4.2.11-0xamarin1)
   libmono-system-messaging4.0-cil (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 => 4.4.2.11-0xamarin1)
   libmono-system-net-http-formatting4.0-cil (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 => 4.4.2.11-0xamarin1)
   libmono-system-net-http-webrequest4.0-cil (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 => 4.4.2.11-0xamarin1)
   libmono-system-net-http4.0-cil (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 => 4.4.2.11-0xamarin1)
   libmono-system-net4.0-cil (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 => 4.4.2.11-0xamarin1)
   libmono-system-numerics4.0-cil (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 => 4.4.2.11-0xamarin1)
   libmono-system-reactive-core2.2-cil (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 => 4.4.2.11-0xamarin1)
   libmono-system-reactive-debugger2.2-cil (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 => 4.4.2.11-0xamarin1)
   libmono-system-reactive-experimental2.2-cil (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 => 4.4.2.11-0xamarin1)
   libmono-system-reactive-interfaces2.2-cil (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 => 4.4.2.11-0xamarin1)
   libmono-system-reactive-linq2.2-cil (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 => 4.4.2.11-0xamarin1)
   libmono-system-reactive-observable-aliases0.0-cil (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 => 4.4.2.11-0xamarin1)
   libmono-system-reactive-platformservices2.2-cil (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 => 4.4.2.11-0xamarin1)
   libmono-system-reactive-providers2.2-cil (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 => 4.4.2.11-0xamarin1)
   libmono-system-reactive-runtime-remoting2.2-cil (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 => 4.4.2.11-0xamarin1)
   libmono-system-reactive-windows-forms2.2-cil (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 => 4.4.2.11-0xamarin1)
   libmono-system-reactive-windows-threading2.2-cil (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 => 4.4.2.11-0xamarin1)
   libmono-system-runtime-caching4.0-cil (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 => 4.4.2.11-0xamarin1)
   libmono-system-runtime-durableinstancing4.0-cil (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 => 4.4.2.11-0xamarin1)
   libmono-system-runtime-serialization-formatters-soap4.0-cil (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 => 4.4.2.11-0xamarin1)
   libmono-system-runtime-serialization4.0-cil (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 => 4.4.2.11-0xamarin1)
   libmono-system-runtime4.0-cil (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 => 4.4.2.11-0xamarin1)
   libmono-system-security4.0-cil (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 => 4.4.2.11-0xamarin1)
   libmono-system-servicemodel-activation4.0-cil (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 => 4.4.2.11-0xamarin1)
   libmono-system-servicemodel-discovery4.0-cil (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 => 4.4.2.11-0xamarin1)
   libmono-system-servicemodel-internals0.0-cil (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 => 4.4.2.11-0xamarin1)
   libmono-system-servicemodel-routing4.0-cil (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 => 4.4.2.11-0xamarin1)
   libmono-system-servicemodel-web4.0-cil (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 => 4.4.2.11-0xamarin1)
   libmono-system-servicemodel4.0a-cil (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 => 4.4.2.11-0xamarin1)
   libmono-system-serviceprocess4.0-cil (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 => 4.4.2.11-0xamarin1)
   libmono-system-threading-tasks-dataflow4.0-cil (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 => 4.4.2.11-0xamarin1)
   libmono-system-transactions4.0-cil (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 => 4.4.2.11-0xamarin1)
   libmono-system-web-abstractions4.0-cil (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 => 4.4.2.11-0xamarin1)
   libmono-system-web-applicationservices4.0-cil (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 => 4.4.2.11-0xamarin1)
   libmono-system-web-dynamicdata4.0-cil (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 => 4.4.2.11-0xamarin1)
   libmono-system-web-extensions-design4.0-cil (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 => 4.4.2.11-0xamarin1)
   libmono-system-web-extensions4.0-cil (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 => 4.4.2.11-0xamarin1)
   libmono-system-web-http-selfhost4.0-cil (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 => 4.4.2.11-0xamarin1)
   libmono-system-web-http-webhost4.0-cil (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 => 4.4.2.11-0xamarin1)
   libmono-system-web-http4.0-cil (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 => 4.4.2.11-0xamarin1)
   libmono-system-web-mvc3.0-cil (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 => 4.4.2.11-0xamarin1)
   libmono-system-web-razor2.0-cil (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 => 4.4.2.11-0xamarin1)
   libmono-system-web-routing4.0-cil (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 => 4.4.2.11-0xamarin1)
   libmono-system-web-services4.0-cil (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 => 4.4.2.11-0xamarin1)
   libmono-system-web-webpages-deployment2.0-cil (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 => 4.4.2.11-0xamarin1)
   libmono-system-web-webpages-razor2.0-cil (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 => 4.4.2.11-0xamarin1)
   libmono-system-web-webpages2.0-cil (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 => 4.4.2.11-0xamarin1)
   libmono-system-web4.0-cil (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 => 4.4.2.11-0xamarin1)
   libmono-system-windows-forms-datavisualization4.0a-cil (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 => 4.4.2.11-0xamarin1)
   libmono-system-windows-forms4.0-cil (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 => 4.4.2.11-0xamarin1)
   libmono-system-windows4.0-cil (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 => 4.4.2.11-0xamarin1)
   libmono-system-xaml4.0-cil (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 => 4.4.2.11-0xamarin1)
   libmono-system-xml-linq4.0-cil (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 => 4.4.2.11-0xamarin1)
   libmono-system-xml-serialization4.0-cil (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 => 4.4.2.11-0xamarin1)
   libmono-system-xml4.0-cil (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 => 4.4.2.11-0xamarin1)
   libmono-system4.0-cil (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 => 4.4.2.11-0xamarin1)
   libmono-tasklets4.0-cil (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 => 4.4.2.11-0xamarin1)
   libmono-webbrowser4.0-cil (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 => 4.4.2.11-0xamarin1)
   libmono-webmatrix-data4.0-cil (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 => 4.4.2.11-0xamarin1)
   libmono-windowsbase4.0-cil (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 => 4.4.2.11-0xamarin1)
   libmono-xbuild-tasks4.0-cil (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 => 4.4.2.11-0xamarin1)
   libmonoboehm-2.0-1 (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 => 4.4.2.11-0xamarin1)
   libmonoboehm-2.0-dev (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 => 4.4.2.11-0xamarin1)
   mono-4.0-gac (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 => 4.4.2.11-0xamarin1)
   mono-csharp-shell (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 => 4.4.2.11-0xamarin1)
   mono-devel (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 => 4.4.2.11-0xamarin1)
   mono-gac (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 => 4.4.2.11-0xamarin1)
   mono-mcs (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 => 4.4.2.11-0xamarin1)
   mono-runtime (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 => 4.4.2.11-0xamarin1)
   mono-runtime-common (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 => 4.4.2.11-0xamarin1)
   mono-runtime-sgen (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 => 4.4.2.11-0xamarin1)
   mono-utils (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 => 4.4.2.11-0xamarin1)
   mono-xbuild (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 => 4.4.2.11-0xamarin1)
   ubuntu-mono (14.04+16.04.20160621-0ubuntu1 => 14.04+16.04.20160804-0ubuntu1)
152 upgraded, 24 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 48.4 MB of archives.
After this operation, 47.0 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
Get:1 http://server.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 libbonobo2-common all 2.32.1-3 [34.7 kB]
Get:2 http://server.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 liborbit-2-0 amd64 1:2.14.19-1build1 [140 kB]
Get:3 http://server.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 libbonobo2-0 amd64 2.32.1-3 [211 kB]
Get:4 http://server.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 libglade2-0 amd64 1:2.6.4-2 [44.6 kB]
Get:5 http://server.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 libgail18 amd64 2.24.30-1ubuntu1 [14.2 kB]
Get:6 http://server.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 libgnomecanvas2-common all 2.30.3-2 [9,080 B]
Get:7 http://server.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 libgnomecanvas2-0 amd64 2.30.3-2 [82.7 kB]      
Get:8 http://server.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 gamin amd64 0.1.10-5 [41.3 kB]              
Get:9 http://server.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 libgamin0 amd64 0.1.10-5 [16.2 kB]          
Get:10 http://server.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 libgnomevfs2-common amd64 1:2.24.4-6.1ubuntu1 [23.0 kB]
Get:11 http://server.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 libgnomevfs2-0 amd64 1:2.24.4-6.1ubuntu1 [213 kB]
Get:12 http://server.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 libgnome2-common all 2.32.1-5ubuntu1 [33.5 kB] 
Get:13 http://server.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 libgnome-2-0 amd64 2.32.1-5ubuntu1 [53.7 kB]   
Get:14 http://server.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 libgnome2-bin amd64 2.32.1-5ubuntu1 [5,040 B]  
Get:15 http://server.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 libgnome2-0 amd64 2.32.1-5ubuntu1 [1,656 B]    
Get:16 http://server.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 libbonoboui2-common all 2.24.5-3ubuntu1 [11.9 kB]
Get:17 http://server.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 libbonoboui2-0 amd64 2.24.5-3ubuntu1 [154 kB]  
Get:18 http://server.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 libgnomeui-common all 2.24.5-3.1 [16.3 kB]     
Get:19 http://server.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 libgnomeui-0 amd64 2.24.5-3.1 [207 kB]         
Get:20 http://server.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 clamav-base all 0.99+dfsg-1ubuntu1.2 [57.9 kB]
Get:21 http://server.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 libclamav7 amd64 0.99+dfsg-1ubuntu1.2 [751 kB]
Get:22 http://server.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 clamav-freshclam amd64 0.99+dfsg-1ubuntu1.2 [115 kB]
Get:23 http://server.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 clamav amd64 0.99+dfsg-1ubuntu1.2 [97.5 kB]
Get:24 http://server.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 libcupsfilters1 amd64 1.8.3-2ubuntu3.1 [80.4 kB]
Get:25 http://server.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 libfontembed1 amd64 1.8.3-2ubuntu3.1 [47.1 kB]
Get:26 http://server.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 ubuntu-mono all 14.04+16.04.20160804-0ubuntu1 [178 kB]
Fetched 48.4 MB                                                                          
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
60621-0ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for gconf2 (3.2.6-3ubuntu6) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-6ubuntu3.1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu5) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.59ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for ca-certificates (20160104ubuntu1) ...


Updating certificates in /etc/ssl/certs...
0 added, 0 removed; done.
Running hooks in /etc/ca-certificates/update.d...
Updating Mono key store
Linux Cert Store Sync - version 4.4.2.0
Synchronize local certs with certs from local Linux trust store.
Copyright 2002, 2003 Motus Technologies. Copyright 2004-2008 Novell. BSD licensed.

I already trust 173, your new list has 173
Import process completed.
Done
done.
Processing triggers for systemd (229-4ubuntu7) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
ureadahead will be reprofiled on next reboot
Setting up libbonobo2-common (2.32.1-3) ...
Setting up liborbit-2-0:amd64 (1:2.14.19-1build1) ...
Setting up libbonobo2-0:amd64 (2.32.1-3) ...
Setting up libglade2-0:amd64 (1:2.6.4-2) ...
Setting up libgail18:amd64 (2.24.30-1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libgnomecanvas2-common (2.30.3-2) ...
Setting up libgnomecanvas2-0:amd64 (2.30.3-2) ...
Setting up libgnomevfs2-common (1:2.24.4-6.1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libgnomevfs2-0:amd64 (1:2.24.4-6.1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libgnome2-common (2.32.1-5ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libgnome-2-0:amd64 (2.32.1-5ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libgnome2-bin (2.32.1-5ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libgnome2-0:amd64 (2.32.1-5ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libbonoboui2-common (2.24.5-3ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libbonoboui2-0:amd64 (2.24.5-3ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libgnomeui-common (2.24.5-3.1) ...
Setting up libgnomeui-0:amd64 (2.24.5-3.1) ...
Setting up libmonosgen-2.0-1 (4.4.2.11-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up libmonosgen-2.0-dev (4.4.2.11-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up libmono-2.0-dev (4.4.2.11-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up libmonoboehm-2.0-1 (4.4.2.11-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up libmonoboehm-2.0-dev (4.4.2.11-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up clamav-base (0.99+dfsg-1ubuntu1.2) ...
Setting up libclamav7 (0.99+dfsg-1ubuntu1.2) ...
Setting up clamav-freshclam (0.99+dfsg-1ubuntu1.2) ...
insserv: warning: current start runlevel(s) (empty) of script `clamav-freshclam' overrides LSB defaults (2 3 4 5).
insserv: warning: current stop runlevel(s) (0 1 2 3 4 5 6) of script `clamav-freshclam' overrides LSB defaults (0 1 6).
Setting up clamav (0.99+dfsg-1ubuntu1.2) ...
Setting up libcupsfilters1:amd64 (1.8.3-2ubuntu3.1) ...
Setting up libfontembed1:amd64 (1.8.3-2ubuntu3.1) ...
Setting up ubuntu-mono (14.04+16.04.20160804-0ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libmono-security4.0-cil (4.4.2.11-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up mono-4.0-gac (4.4.2.11-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up mono-gac (4.4.2.11-0xamarin1) ...
* Installing 1 assembly from libnunit-console-runner2.6.3-cil into Mono
* Installing 1 assembly from libnunit-core2.6.3-cil into Mono
* Installing 1 assembly from libnunit-core-interfaces2.6.3-cil into Mono
* Installing 1 assembly from libnunit-framework2.6.3-cil into Mono
* Installing 1 assembly from libnunit-mocks2.6.3-cil into Mono
* Installing 1 assembly from libnunit-util2.6.3-cil into Mono
* Installing 1 assembly from policy.2.6.nunit-console-runner into Mono
* Installing 1 assembly from policy.2.6.nunit.core into Mono
* Installing 1 assembly from policy.2.6.nunit.core.interfaces into Mono
* Installing 1 assembly from policy.2.6.nunit.framework into Mono
* Installing 1 assembly from policy.2.6.nunit.mocks into Mono
* Installing 1 assembly from policy.2.6.nunit.util into Mono
Setting up mono-runtime-common (4.4.2.11-0xamarin1) ...
Installing new version of config file /etc/mono/2.0/machine.config ...
Installing new version of config file /etc/mono/4.0/machine.config ...
Installing new version of config file /etc/mono/4.5/machine.config ...
Installing new version of config file /etc/mono/config ...


Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for ca-certificates (20160104ubuntu1) ...
Updating certificates in /etc/ssl/certs...
0 added, 0 removed; done.
Running hooks in /etc/ca-certificates/update.d...
Updating Mono key store
Linux Cert Store Sync - version 4.4.2.0
Synchronize local certs with certs from local Linux trust store.
Copyright 2002, 2003 Motus Technologies. Copyright 2004-2008 Novell. BSD licensed.

I already trust 173, your new list has 173
Import process completed.
Done
done.
```

Answer (score 0):

That's just Mono updating. Mono is a library that allows you to run C# on linux. Xamarin is the company who makes Mono.
All in all, it's nothing to worry about.